# Dimension 1 reducible variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, krull-dimension

I was wondering if it was possible to have a dimension 1 affine variety be a finite union of points, i.e. does a variety have dimension 0 iff it is a finite union of points (over an algebraically closed field)?

On a related note, is it possible to have a reducible curve, i.e. a reducible variety of dimension 1? Thank you!

Comment: $xy=0\mbox{}\mbox{}$

Comment: Can you please add your definitions of affine variety, variety and dimension?